# How to chose the limit of speed for a stop

Tags: classification, computational-statistics

I have mouse events data(mouse events are generated when the mouse is moving). What would be the best way to calculate when the mouse is stopped? I see two cases: for `dT` time thre are no event Or mouse moving speed <= `minV`. And `minV` is not zero because mouse can shiver a little even if it is stopped. I can't make experiments, I just have raw recorded data (unsupervised learning).

Comment: There are many practicable, interesting, illustrated, fully-coded answers to this question (in the context of eye tracking, which is exactly the same problem) at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2711.